# createNotFoundException is not working in symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony 3.2. I don't know what happened here when I link the page in to this one

```
hello_dev.com/app_dev.php/portal/68/facilities/120
```

I get this kind of 500 http error
[image]
but when I link this to this one

```
hello_dev.com/app_dev.php/portal/68/facilities/119
```

I get this error page which is correct
[image]
If you notice it, I change only the id of the facility 120 to 119. All want is the same error 404 page. Do I miss something about the setup in symfony? And here is the code of my backend. It just simple action code.

```
/**
     * @Route("/{transactionId}/facilities/{transactionFacilityId}", name="portal_get_facility")
     * @param Request $request
     * @throws \RangeException
     * @throws QueryException
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getFacilityAction(Request $request) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Invalid facility');
     }
```

Comment: On hard 500 type errors there should usually be some error logged the php_error logfile. Maybe that could help. On first look from what you posted here this should probably not happen and looks fine.

Comment: Any idea what's the difference between 119 and 120? That could give a clue.

Comment: sorry late reply. I found out there is the code in event handler use the route `portal_get_facility`. It returns the empty value.  @Joe you are right. I did that way by checking the php_error.